# Function not hit on submission (django)

Tags: python, django

### views.py

```
class StatisticsIndexView(StaffRestrictedMixin, TemplateView):
    model = Statistics()
    template_name = 'loanwolf/statistics/index.html'
    form = StatisticsBaseForm()

    def home(self):
       import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
       redirect_url = self.request.GET.get('period')
       return redirect_url

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

        context = super(StatisticsIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'applications_by_state': ApplicationsByState(),
            'applications_calendar': ApplicationsCalendar(),
            'new_customers_calendar': NewCustomersCalendar(),
            'statistics': Statistics(),
            'form': StatisticsBaseForm(),
        })
        return context
```

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[

    url(r'^$', login_required(
        StatisticsIndexView.as_view()), name='index'),

]
```

I put a breakpoint in the `home()` and `get_context_data()` method, but once I run a submit button,  it stopped only in the `get_context_data()`. Why did it not stop on `home()` method? How could I override `StatisticsIndexView.as_view()` to add some new methods? I can't understand how I can ask `home()` method to be used. Be aware that `home()` is a new method, so not overridden.

Comment: home and get_context_data method are different.

Comment: do you hit 2 method at same time ?

Comment: as home method is not called then why it executes breakpoint?

Comment: Why do you expect home to called? is it part of the StaffRestrictedMixin you are inheriting from?  Only methods which are called in one of the base objects or called in a method you are overriding would be called

Comment: @alonisser I want that if `self.request.GET` is empty to do something and if, for instance `Per week` is in `self.request.GET` to do something else. What do you suggest? To be honnest, I have a list of customers created each day, each week, each month and each year. I want the application to give me the mean of customer per period (day, week, month and year). Do I need to put the logic in the model?

Comment: @J.Doe You can put the Logic in a model or just a plain python module or even as a class method in the view. But you would need to call it somewhere. What does this question have to do the calling the mysterious "home" method

Comment: Again: Why do you expect `home()` to be called at all? If you do not have any additional code on top of [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/#supporting-other-http-methods), it would be called for a HTTP method called `HOME`. Which is obviously not the same as `PUT` or `POST` form submission ...